# preparing android web view for next activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-webview

I am a new android developer, I am trying to figure out how to initialize some activity, so that when I wish to show it later from any other activity (more than one), it will already be initialized. Let's assume the init takes some time, which is why I want to pre-init the activity in the first place... The activity contains web content inside a webview.

The problem is the init should occur asynchronously, I don't want to block the UI while performing the init, and also once the activity and its webview are ready, I want to be able to call them from the main thread.

What is the proper flow to implement this?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't prepare the Activity. You should do the init part in the Activity `onCreate()` method.

If you don't want to block the UI, then do the async work in an other thread. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this.